# SVG файл в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, svg

Как можно скопировать файл svg? И как правильно потом его залить на сайт WordPress?

Есть код на сайте донора:

```
<a href="/kompleksnaya-strategiya/" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mainpage__service">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 380 280" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="mainpage__service__svg"><line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="380" y2="0"></line><line class="left" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="280"></line><line class="bottom" x1="0" y1="280" x2="380" y2="280"></line><line class="right" x1="380" y1="0" x2="380" y2="280"></line></svg>
    <div class="mainpage__service__caption">
        <svg class="img-responsive mainpage__service__img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 122 78"><path class="st0" d="M99.5 10h-78c-1.6 0-3 1.3-3 3v52c0 1.6 1.3 3 3 3h78.1c1.6 0 3-1.3 3-3V13c-.1-1.7-1.4-3-3.1-3zm1.3 55c0 .7-.6 1.3-1.3 1.3h-78c-.7 0-1.3-.6-1.3-1.3V19.7h80.6V65zm0-47H20.2v-5c0-.7.6-1.3 1.3-1.3h78.1c.7 0 1.3.6 1.3 1.3l-.1 5zm-3.7-3.9h-1.7c-.5 0-.8.4-.8.9s.4.9.8.9h1.7c.5 0 .8-.4.8-.9s-.3-.9-.8-.9zm-6.5 0h-1.7c-.5 0-.8.4-.8.9s.4.9.8.9h1.7c.5 0 .8-.4.8-.9s-.4-.9-.8-.9zm-6.6 0h-1.7c-.5 0-.8.4-.8.9s.4.9.8.9H84c.5 0 .8-.4.8-.9.1-.5-.3-.9-.8-.9zM72.2 35.6v14.9c0 .5.4.9.8.9h21.5c.5 0 .8-.4.8-.9V35.6c0-.5-.4-.9-.8-.9H73c-.5 0-.8.4-.8.9zm1.7.9h19.8v13.2H73.9V36.5zm-22.6 8H28.7c-.5 0-.8.4-.8.9v5.1c0 .5.4.9.8.9h22.6c.5 0 .8-.4.8-.9v-5.1c.1-.5-.3-.9-.8-.9zm-.8 5.1H29.6v-3.4h20.9v3.4zM28.7 35.2c-.5 0-.8.4-.8.9v5.1c0 .5.4.9.8.9h22.6c.5 0 .8-.4.8-.9v-5.1c0-.5-.4-.9-.8-.9H28.7zm21.8 1.7v3.4H29.6v-3.4h20.9z"/><path class="st1" d="M72.8 25.1c1.3.2 2.5.6 3.7 1 .1 0 .2.1.3.1.3 0 .7-.2.8-.6.2-.4-.1-.9-.5-1.1-1.3-.5-2.6-.8-4-1.1-.5-.1-.9.2-1 .7-.1.5.2.9.7 1zM66.4 50c.1.3.5.5.8.5.1 0 .2 0 .3-.1 1.1-.4 2.3-.6 3.6-.6.5 0 .8-.4.8-.9s-.4-.9-.8-.9c-1.5 0-2.9.2-4.2.7-.5.4-.7.9-.5 1.3zM61.1 55.9c.1.1.2.1.4.1.3 0 .6-.2.8-.5.6-1.2 1.3-2.2 2.1-3 .3-.3.3-.9 0-1.2-.3-.3-.9-.3-1.2 0-1 1-1.8 2.1-2.5 3.5-.1.4 0 .9.4 1.1zM65 24.7c1.3-.1 2.7-.1 4-.1.5 0 .9-.3.9-.8s-.3-.9-.8-.9c-1.3-.1-2.8 0-4.1.1-.5 0-.8.4-.8.9-.1.5.3.8.8.8zM57.2 26.4c.1 0 .2 0 .3-.1 1.2-.4 2.4-.8 3.7-1.1.5-.1.8-.5.7-1-.1-.5-.5-.8-1-.7-1.4.3-2.7.7-4 1.1-.4.2-.7.7-.5 1.1.1.4.4.7.8.7zM82.3 32.9c0 .5.4.9.8.9h3.8c.4 0 .7-.2.8-.6l.7-2.6c.1-.5-.1-.9-.6-1.1-.4-.1-.9.1-1.1.6l-.4 1.2c-.2 0-.4 0-.6.2-.2.1-.2.3-.3.5H83c-.3.1-.7.4-.7.9zM79.9 27.8c1.1.6 2.2 1.4 3.1 2.2.2.1.4.2.5.2.2 0 .5-.1.6-.3.3-.4.3-.9-.1-1.2-1.1-.9-2.2-1.7-3.4-2.4-.4-.2-.9-.1-1.2.3 0 .4.1 1 .5 1.2zM84 14.1h-1.7c-.5 0-.8.4-.8.9s.4.9.8.9H84c.5 0 .8-.4.8-.9.1-.5-.3-.9-.8-.9zM90.6 14.1h-1.7c-.5 0-.8.4-.8.9s.4.9.8.9h1.7c.5 0 .8-.4.8-.9s-.4-.9-.8-.9zM97.1 14.1h-1.7c-.5 0-.8.4-.8.9s.4.9.8.9h1.7c.5 0 .8-.4.8-.9s-.3-.9-.8-.9zM25.5 25.6s.6-.1 1.7-.1c.7 0 1.4 0 2.2.1h.1c.4 0 .8-.3.8-.8s-.3-.9-.8-.9c-.8-.1-1.5-.1-2.3-.1-1.1 0-1.8.1-1.9.1-.5.1-.8.5-.8.9.2.5.6.8 1 .8zM33.2 26.2c1.3.3 2.5.7 3.6 1.2.1.1.2.1.3.1.3 0 .6-.2.8-.5.2-.4 0-.9-.4-1.1-1.2-.5-2.5-1-3.9-1.3-.5-.1-.9.2-1 .6-.1.4.1.9.6 1zM50.3 30.4c.2 0 .4-.1.6-.2.9-.8 2-1.6 3.1-2.3.4-.2.5-.8.3-1.2-.2-.4-.8-.5-1.2-.3-1.2.7-2.3 1.5-3.4 2.4-.4.3-.4.8-.1 1.2.3.3.5.4.7.4zM42.9 32c.2.2.4.3.7.3.2 0 .4-.1.5-.2.4-.3.4-.8.1-1.2-.9-1.1-1.9-2-3-2.9-.4-.3-.9-.2-1.2.2-.3.4-.2.9.2 1.2 1 .7 1.9 1.6 2.7 2.6zM59.6 63.3s.1.1.2.1c0 0 .1 0 .1.1.1 0 .2.1.3.1.1 0 .2 0 .3-.1 0 0 .1 0 .1-.1.1 0 .1-.1.2-.1l3.7-3.4c.3-.3.4-.9.1-1.2-.3-.3-.9-.4-1.2-.1L61 60.8c0-.6.1-1.1.2-1.7.1-.5-.2-.9-.7-1-.5-.1-.9.2-1 .7-.1.6-.2 1.2-.2 1.9l-2.2-2c-.3-.3-.9-.3-1.2.1-.3.3-.3.9.1 1.2l3.6 3.3zM44.8 34.9V35.2c.1.4.5.7 1.1.7.5 0 .9-.3 1.1-.7.2-.5.7-1.3 1.4-2.2.3-.4.2-.9-.2-1.2-.4-.3-.9-.2-1.2.2-.5.7-1 1.4-1.2 1.9-.1 0-.3 0-.4.1-.4.2-.6.5-.6.9z"/>
        </svg>
        <div class="mainpage__service__title">КОМПЛЕКСНАЯ<br>PERFORMANCE<br>СТРАТЕГИЯ</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

WordPress запрещает работу с файлами svg. Объясняется это соображениями безопасности. Залить svg-файл в библиотеку медиафайлов не получится. У вас два варианта:

1. Залить файл по ftp в подпапку вашей темы, скажем, `/images` и сослаться на него в html.
2. Установить плагин [SVG Support](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/svg-support/) и работать с svg-файлом так же, как с jpeg или png - закачивать в библиотеку, добавлять в записи и проч.

**UPDATE**

Не обратил внимания на то, как svg представлен в коде. В вашем случае вы можете:

1. Скопировать html-код svg изображения и вставить в запись или php-код страницы WordPress.
2. Попробовать создать из тега ... файл .svg и далее с ним работать, как указано выше. Для этого текст ... поместите в текстовый файл с расширением svg (да, svg-это текстовые файлы) и добавьте сверху строчку

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: обращаться к файлу svg вот так?
<svg scr="..." >

Comment: нет, <img src="/wp-content/themes/моя-тема/images/мойфайл.svg" ....>

Comment: @KAGGDesign  теме twenty seventeen поищи `function twentyseventeen_include_svg_icons` ;) (эт я про запрет работы ВП. Загрузка в медиатеку - это совсем не запрет работы)

Comment: @SeVlad да знаю я все это, и на своих сайтах вовсю использую svg. Потому и написал про залить через ftp.